# RStudio not reading system variables when started via launcher

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, launcher

I'm having a few problems with system environment variables with RStudio. In ~/.bashrc some custom environment variables are set which I want to access in my program using Sys.getenv().

When I'm calling Rstudio from the command line, this works fine. However, when I'm using the Ubuntu launch function (Alt+F2) to start RStudio, my environment variables are not found. For portability, I would kind of prefer for this to work, too...
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find Rstudio's desktop launcher. In Ubuntu, launchers are simple text files with the extension `.desktop`. You can read more about the file format [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles). The most common locations for these are `/home/user/.local/share/applications` (user-specific) and `/usr/local/share/applications` (system-wide). The easiest way to edit these files is to use an app called menulibre.

You can install menulibre by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

You can then use menulibre to find and edit the Rstudio launcher.

I have just tried using `Sys.getenv()` on my Rstudio installation, and it works fine. My Rstudio launcher command is `/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio %F`

Edit: I am running Rstudio Version 0.99.491